# Update Bokeh Version on Pythonanywhere hosted webapplication

Tags: bokeh, pythonanywhere

I'm struggling to update the Bokeh version on my pythonanywhere hosted webapplication.

I'm wanting to install Bokeh 2.4.3, however the pythonanywhere server only has Bokeh 1.3.4 installed.

I've tried updating through the bashconsole

```
10:53 ~ $ pip3.7 install --user update bokeh
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Requirement already satisfied: update in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bokeh in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: style==1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from update) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (6.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.3 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.10 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.7 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bokeh) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.7->bokeh) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->bokeh) (2.4.2)
```

However this hasn't worked. So I've tried uninstalling Bokeh, and with the intension of re-installing however I get an error:

```
411:03 ~ $ pip3.7 uninstall bokeh
Uninstalling bokeh-1.3.4:
  Would remove:
    /usr/bin/bokeh
    /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh-1.3.4.dist-info/*
    /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 566, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/usr/bin/bokeh' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-gd_j1_do/bokeh'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 79, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 755, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 338, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 581, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/bokeh'
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: The immediate error seems to be that the uninstall script tries to rename something, where source and destination (/usr and /tmp) are on different permissions. I don't know much about `pip`, but can you tell it not to use /tmp for its temporary files? If this does not help, I would post the problem on [su], because it is about uninstalling software, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can't uninstall pre-installed packages from https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/

The best way to upgrade would be update of the whole system image from "fishnchips" to "haggis". See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ChangingSystemImage